# Is it wrong to store a user's ID in a table to create ownership?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple model of events that need to be owned by a single use. What I want to do is just store the user's ID in the events table as a foreign key. Then, on lookup, I'll query for all the events that are owned by that user. Simple stuff.

The problem is that I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and the Entity Framework and as such, it seems that it's not that easy. Or rather, there seems to be a more enlightened way to do things and, as I'm trying to piece information together, I'm thinking this is above my current skill level.

Will I be shooting myself in the foot if I go the "easy" way and just store the user's ID as a string? If so, I'd really appreciate pointing me to some recommended articles or videos that describe this concept and how to do it.

Comment: "user's ID as a string", why as string?

Comment: Because it's a GUID like "8941b426-8f75-58da-a342-41da94273cd8"

Comment: So use the guid data type and map a 1:n association.

Comment: "and map a 1:n association" That's what my question is about.

Comment: Are you using database first or code first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question is vague, but I also think I understand what you are asking.  It seems like you are asking if you should create the relationship between the user table and the events table or simply just store the user id in the events table without the relationship.

In short order, yes, you will be "shooting yourself in the foot" in multiple ways.  First, having foreign keys between related entities enforces integrity into your database.  Meaning you can't tie an event to a non-existent user.  Second, SQL uses these foreign keys to better index and query your tables.  Lastly, you lose a lot of the abilities of Entity Framework such as being able to do the following:

```
var user = db.Users.First(x=>x.Id == userId);
var userName = user.Name;
var events = user.Events.ToList();
```

In this example, I only have to reference my DataContext once, yet, can access any properties or related entities to that object.  Of course, this works both ways.

```
var event = db.Events.First(x=>x.Id == eventId);
var eventOwner = event.User;
```

With that said, [this article should give you some really good guidance on doing relationships and code first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx).  Using your example, it should be as easy as the following:

```
public partial class User{
   public User(){       
       this.Events = new HashSet<Event>();
   }

   public Guid UserId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   //...other properties as needed
   public virtual ICollection<Event> Events {get;set;}
}

public partial class Event{
   public int EventId {get;set;}
   public Guid UserId {get;set;}
   //...other properties
   public virtual User User {get;set;}
}
```

As for storing something as a string that is actually a GUID, the foreign key will not allow you to map to columns of different data types.  Either they both need to be varchar or that both need to be Guid (uniqueidentifier in SQL).  Keep with the GUID, better indexing than a random set of characters.

Comment: I agree with your assessment of my question being vague, and yes, you understand what I was trying to ask. The problem is that I don't know enough to ask the question properly. Thanks for making an effort!